# How do I weight two PathPrefixs in traefik 2.x

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress

Given I have the following `PathPrefix` configurations, *in this order*:

- PathPrefix(`/us/booking`) -> points to an application called "Bar"
- PathPrefix(`/us/bookingconfirmation`) -> points to an application called "Foo"

At present, `/us/bookingconfirmation` is served by application `Bar` but *should* be served by `Foo`.

Moving the `Foo` application above `Bar` isn't feasible, ideally, I'm looking for a weight to be applied.

How do I weight `/us/bookingconfirmation` so that it's served by `Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is `Priority`.

See https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#priority